# In IntelliJ, how to set the Android API level

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using the latest and greatest IntelliJ Community edition.  My application runs fine on the android emulator.  However, I need the emulator to better match the Kindle Fire.  I made the configuration changes in the AVD Manager (including setting device to API 10.)

When I went to my project to configure the project to target the new virtual device, I got the following message:  "Build target of AVD DEV3 is not compatible with your build target."

It didn't take much work to figure out that the issue is related to my choice of API 10.

I don't know where I tell my project to use API 10.  I looked all over and didn't see any references to the API level at all.  Any ideas?

*EDIT*

I added

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml file and was able to select the new device.  I'm starting it up now.

Comment: Why do you say **latest and greatest IntelliJ**, is it better than eclipse?

Comment: It is to me.  Eclipse is a totally competent IDE, however.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial for using IntelliJ for Android Development?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial for Android development with IntelliJ: http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_Android_in_IntelliJ_IDEA

Comment: @GauravAgarwal I find IntelliJ very intuitive and--for me, more importantly--much, much faster than Eclipse at just about everything.

Answer (score 4):

The answer above is no longer true in Intellij (using gradle)

Now `<uses-sdk>` is ignored in the AndroidManifest.xml, it is automatically added to the built manifest file.  To change the version, go to the 'build.gradle' file and look at the minSdkVersion.

Comment: That link goes back to this same page, so maybe you meant to post a different link.  I'm using IntelliJ, but not gradle, so it still respects my AndroidManifest.xml setting.

Comment: Thanks - fixed on both counts

Comment: how to set target sdk in intellij?
for example, I have an AVD with API_19 but the target sdk is 24

Answer (score 2):

As Tony and Blundell mention, the answer is to declare your `minSdkVersion` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.  In this way, the application will be allowed to launch on any AVDs that at least meet the `minSdkVersion`.

Here's more documentation on the `<uses-sdk>` tag:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Set this value in the Gradle file - as shown here:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kotlinconverterapp"
        **minSdkVersion 26**
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```